# How to get handlebars to call get() method on context?

Tags: ember.js, handlebars.js

I'm using handlebars by itself with an Ember Object as context. I'd like it so that it works as it does in Ember+HTMLBars, where it seemingly calls get() instead of assuming context is a POJO.

```
var C = Ember.Object.extend({
  value: Ember.computed(function() { return "hello"; })
});
var template = Handlebars.compile("My ember object: {{value}}");
var str = template(C.create());

assert.equal(str, "My ember object: hello"); // Fails. str == "My ember object: [object Object]"
```

Is there a way to have handlebars call get()?

Comment: I see mention of the feature in old Ember source code, but it's not clear to me how they do it. https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/blob/v1.9.1/packages/ember-handlebars-compiler/lib/main.js#L47

Comment: could try something like `{{get this value}}` maybe.. but also, if you're looking to use ember/handlebars standalone, you might be interested to use [Glimmer](https://glimmerjs.com/)

Comment: I could use a get helper, however, it feels messy. The get helper would have to be included in all my mustaches.

Comment: Ah, found the docs for nameLookup. For others wanting to do this, see the very bottom section "Example for the compiler API" here: https://github.com/wycats/handlebars.js/blob/c9970200a04a8629b5e9b1ed3c540d391ab00f26/docs/compiler-api.md

Answer (score 0):

You can add a helper that is called automatically during name lookup using the [Handlebars Compiler API](https://github.com/wycats/handlebars.js/blob/c9970200a04a8629b5e9b1ed3c540d391ab00f26/docs/compiler-api.md).

```
function MyCompiler() {
  Handlebars.JavaScriptCompiler.apply(this, arguments);
}
MyCompiler.prototype = new Handlebars.JavaScriptCompiler();

MyCompiler.prototype.nameLookup = function(parent, name, type) {
  if (type === 'context') {
    return this.source.functionCall('helpers.get', '', [parent, JSON.stringify(name)])
  } else {
    return Handlebars.JavaScriptCompiler.prototype.nameLookup.call(this, parent, name, type);
  }
}

var env = Handlebars.create();
env.registerHelper('get', function(parent, name) {
  return parent.get(name);
})

env.JavaScriptCompiler = MyCompiler;
```

And now the original example in the question works.

```
var C = Ember.Object.extend({
  value: Ember.computed(function() { return "hello"; })
});
var template = env.compile("My ember object: {{value}}");
var str = template(C.create());

assert.equal(str, "My ember object: hello"); // PASS!
```

This answer is based on [this jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/9D88g/85/).